# ROS on ROBOT EPSON

Tags: ros, ros2, robotic-arm

Would you know if it is possible to control an EPSON robot with ROS, in order to get out of the dependence on the EPSON ecosystem.
I'm a beginner looking for a solution, sorry if my question isn't very precise.

Thank you very much,

Sincerely

Comment: I'm not familiar with this platform, but generally, ROS drivers work by wrapping the manufacturer-provided software... so you could use ROS to get around interacting with EPSON directly, but it would still be a dependency.